# Whats the equivalent for "-webkit-border-vertical-spacing" attribute in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, primefaces, webkit, mozilla

I am using a primefaces selectOneMenu on my page. The combobox appeared stretched on Chrome which i fixed setting the -webkit-border-vertical-spacing property as follows

```
.selectOnDialog{
    z-index: 10; 
    opacity: 100; 
    width:290px!important;
    -webkit-border-vertical-spacing:1px;
}
```

But I am not able to find the Mozilla Firefox equivalent property and hence the combobox is stretched on Firefox. Please help.

I have tried searching http://help.dottoro.com , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Mozilla_Extensions but no success yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
border-spacing: [horizontal] [vertical]
```

Ex.

```
border-spacing: 0 1px;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing